# pylucence cannot find a word that was presented in the text which indexed earlier

Tags: python, indexing, lucene, pylucene

I use pylucence 9.4.1 to index a document and I just noticed a weird problem. There are some words, e.g. 'baby', that are present in the document but pylucene is unable to find them in the index.

This is my code to index the document:
(The document can be downloaded from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/jrobischon/wikipedia-movie-plots).

```
filepath = os.getcwd() + '/' + 'wiki_movie_plots_deduped.csv'


def indexDocument(title, year, plot):
    ft = FieldType()
    ft.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
    ft.setStored(True)
    ft.setTokenized(True)
    ft.setStoreTermVectors(True)
    ft.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(True)
    ft.setStoreTermVectorPositions(True)
    doc = document.Document()
    doc.add(document.Field("Title", title, ft))
    doc.add(document.Field("Plot", plot, ft))    
    writer.addDocument(doc)

    
def CloseWriter():
    writer.close()
    
    
def makeInvertedIndex(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    print(df.columns)
    docid = 0
    for i in df.index:
        print(docid, '-', df['Title'][i])
        indexDocument(df['Title'][i], df['Release Year'][i], df['Plot'][i])
        docid += 1
  

indexPath = File('index/').toPath()
indexDir = FSDirectory.open(indexPath)
writerConfig = IndexWriterConfig(EnglishAnalyzer())
writer = IndexWriter(indexDir, writerConfig)
inverted = makeInvertedIndex(filepath)

CloseWriter()
```

This is the code to search the created index for a keyword:

```
keyword = 'baby'
fieldname = 'Title'
result = list()

indexPath = File('index/').toPath()
directory = FSDirectory.open(indexPath)

analyzer = StandardAnalyzer()
reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory)
searcher = IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(directory))
query = QueryParser(fieldname, analyzer).parse(keyword)
print('query', query)
numdocs = searcher.count(query)
print("#-docs:", numdocs)
    
    
searcher.setSimilarity(BM25Similarity(1.2,0.75))
scoreDocs = searcher.search(query, 1000).scoreDocs # it returns TopDocs object containing scoreDocs and totalHits
# scoreDoc object contains docId and score
print('total hit:', searcher.search(query, 100).totalHits)
print("%s total matching documents" % (len(scoreDocs)))
```

Any help to understand the problem is appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, just a quick observation: you are using `EnglishAnalyzer` to index the data, but `StandardAnalyzer` for querying. I don't recall off the top of my head if the `EnglishAnalyzer` performs transformation to lowercase - so maybe try using the `StandardAnalyzer` in both cases. Generally, you typically (but not always) want to use the same analyzer for indexing and for querying. Maybe you are indexing `Baby` but searching for `baby`.

Comment: You should create a [mre]. I doubt anyone is going to download all that raw data you linked to. Just use some hard-coded data in the question to demonstrate the issue, using the least amount of code (and data) necessary. Show _explicitly_ what output you get and what output you expect. Add all this to the question.